# Debian (Jessie) install old package from archive (as Lenny or Squeeze)

Tags: debian, packages, linux-distributions, installation-package

I tried many searches, then I cannot find the solution, here is my problem.

My server is debian with Jessie (8) distribution, but I have to install a old package now archived which was available for old distributions like Lenny (5)

The package name is : **ttf2pt1**
Can be found [here](http://ttf2pt1.sourceforge.net/download.html) (Official) or [here](https://archive.debian.net/source/lenny/ttf2pt1) (Debian archive)

I tried to edit my *sources.list* with old sources urls but nothing change, I got several errors like :

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ttf2pt1`

`E: The value 'lenny' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
E: The value 'lenny' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

What is the right way to install an **old package** onto an **actual stable distribution** ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found alone the solution.

I was true to edit my source list

But I should add : `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main`

Then `apt-get update`

Then I can install my old package :)

Comment: Another possibility (I'd say, a better one) is to manually fetch the `.deb` file of the package of interest (using `wget` for instance) and then installing it directly using `dpkg -i path/to/that/file.deb`.  The upside of this approach is that it doesn't pollute APT cache with obsolete information from the archived release.

Comment: The downside is that if the package to be installed depends on other packages, you'd need to sort this situation out. And that's when the situation becomes interesting: if the subject package has "weak" dependencies (say, it depens on package `foo` without specifying its version or has a lax version specification) you will be able to get the packages it requires just by `apt install`ing them.

Comment: ... But if it depends on older versions of some packages, you'll have a clear hint you will probably need to "forward-port" that old package by obtaining its source package and building it for the current stable distribution -- possibly with some due adjustments first.  It's like backporting a package from testing/unstable but in the other direction ;-)

Comment: Wow, I like the first solution. If I knew it I'd try it
Because really it was a small package and just fetch the .deb could be a right simple solution
Now I should have to clean my package list cache because of what I did
thank you very much